# How to fix to center of the screen the textview in android?

Tags: android, textview

help me please. :(

how can i put the TextView in the center of the screen, dynamically?
i mean, any type of screen resolution its fix in the center of the screen.

thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **Relative Layout** and in it add your **Text View** with the following attributes.

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic Android principle. You should read through the [Android Developers course.](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) It will show you how to do things like this.

To answer your question, use a layout that has the layout parameters of match_parent and set the gravity to center like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Or programmatically:

```
relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: sorry im just a beginner :(

Comment: @Lestr1992 It's no biggie. No one minds helping you out. I think that you might find it easier, however, if you read through that. It will answer a lot questions and make you a more productive programmer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put it to Relative layout and add

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Or in linear layout that matches the parent height and width use this code

```
 android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Comment: i tried that, but every time i test it to my friends tablet the text is not in center. but on my phone its works.

Comment: @Lestr1992 do you have any layout for tablet like layout-sw600dp or something?

Answer (score 0):

you can place the gravity for a `textview` as below:

```
 <YourTextView>.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: I think you have hard-coded layout_width and layout_height of your TextView. Thats the problem, else my solution works. Don't hard-code. Its a bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```